# How does the execution scope work in jest for mockImplementation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm trying to work out execution scopes in jest tests.

I have a react component with the following line being executed during the render:

```
console.log(fun().m1());
```

Here's three example of jest of tests

```
import React from 'react';
import Enzyme, { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import SimpleInput from './SimpleInput';
import { fun } from './util';
jest.mock('./util', () => ({
  fun: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({ m1: jest.fn() })),
}));

describe('SimpleInput', () => {
  test("should have '' initialValue by default", () => {
    const simpleInput = shallow(<SimpleInput />);
    expect(simpleInput.prop('value')).toBe('');
  });
});
```

Outcome:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'm1' of undefined
```

If I move the mockImplementation to the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import Enzyme, { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import SimpleInput from './SimpleInput';
import { fun } from './util';
jest.mock('./util');

describe('SimpleInput', () => {
  fun.mockImplementation(() => ({ m1: jest.fn() }));

  test("should have '' initialValue by default", () => {
    const simpleInput = shallow(<SimpleInput />);
    expect(simpleInput.prop('value')).toBe('');
  });
});
```

Outcome:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'm1' of undefined
```

And finally:

```
import React from 'react';
import Enzyme, { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import SimpleInput from './SimpleInput';
import { fun } from './util';
jest.mock('./util');

describe('SimpleInput', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    fun.mockImplementation(() => ({ m1: jest.fn() }));
  });

  test("should have '' initialValue by default", () => {
    const simpleInput = shallow(<SimpleInput />);
    expect(simpleInput.prop('value')).toBe('');
  });
});
```

Outcome: it passes.

My question is if I can't execute the mock implementation outside of the beforeEach or each particular test case, how can I add the following to the jest setup files which seems to be failing at the moment:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'matchMedia', {
   writable: true,
   value: jest.fn().mockImplementation((query) => ({
     matches: false,
     media: query,
     onchange: null,
     addListener, // Deprecated
     removeListener: jest.fn(), // Deprecated
     addEventListener: jest.fn(),
     removeEventListener: jest.fn(),
     dispatchEvent: jest.fn(),
   })),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In such case, you may want to use [`jest.spyOn`](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname). This will add a spy over the original method and you then can perform any kind of mocking you need :)

```js
let performanceNowSpy

beforeEach(() => {
    performanceNowSpy = jest.spyOn(window.performance, 'now')
})

afterEach(() => {
    performanceNowSpy.mockReset()
})

afterAll(() => {
    performanceNowSpy.mockRestore()
})

test('meaningful test name', () => {
    performanceNowSpy.mockReturnValueOnce(0)
    // A simple example.
    // `performance.now()` can be called from another module too.
    expect(performance.now()).toBe(0)
})
```

Comment: thanks, I'm aware of spyOn, but was looking for clarity on the execution scope.  Especially with the case of creating jest fn inside mock implementations outside of the specific tests.  Then to take this one step further and adding mocking functions in setup files - so that it's available for all tests.